# more than one attachment field

Tags: 2010, infopath, security, custom-list

We are planning to retire one of our old fashion tools and currently evaluating Sharepoint 2010.

in our current tool, we have 3 different attachment sections two of which are visible to customer, and the other is used internally.

I could  add attachment column to a custom list. I suspect that it is not possible(I might well be wrong). if so, how can I achieve this? is that possible to filter visible attachment based on the logged user?

if it is possible to add another attachment section to the form, could you tell me how?

Regards

Comment: Given the structure that is exposed in the object model, I seriously doubt this is possible but would love to be proved wrong.

Comment: Very interesting question, thanks! However, I see you have `infopath` tag binded to your question. Could you clarify, do you mean only infopath solution is acceptable or it can be an *ASPX* form solution as well?

Comment: @omlin yes I am planning to use infopath forms. I am not sure about aspx solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated this some time ago, and while I didn't do a POC on it, having multiple attachments can be done using InfoPath's repeating control.

But after that you need to go under the hood and implement the attachment uploading in code behind.

During attachment uploading of the items that are not to be shown to the customer, you would probably want to have the attachments on separate list(s) and reference to those using lookup. This way you could use item level permissions for the internal attachments, or preferably user/group specific folders on that list to minimize the amount of ACLs.

You will also need to modify the Display and Edit forms, but they should be pretty straightforward after you have the New form functionality implemented.